# What is a spoiler tag or spoiler quote and how would you create one?

Tags: discussion, support

I have seen spoiler tags or quotes (not sure if terminology is correct) on other SE sites. I can't find anything in the help topics that addresses them. Please see  [example](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/a-mirror-of-events) . Any idea how to create these? Would there be any use for them on SA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret to making a spoiler like this one

> I am hidden

is to start a line with a right angle bracket followed by a bang, like this: `>!`. A useful trick: if you don't know how to do something in Markdown (the language used for formatting SE posts) but have an example, just use the Edit link on the example and you will see the source, even if your reputation on the target site is so low a real edit would need approval. Look at it, then leave the page without actually submitting an edit.

There are features which are *not* supported across the network, such as the rendering of mathematical formulas entered in a special LaTeX like language - this is only available on Math and other sites which need it, because the rendering engine slows the pages down. But other features, including the hidden paragraphs, are available everywhere.

I have never in my time on Seasoned advice seen a need for hidden paragraphs, they are typical for sites which handle movies, books and so on, where you don't want to read about plot turns too early. But if a user ever feels the need to use one, they are available.

Comment: But we have all those food safety questions!

Comment: Ha! @Jefromi! Different type of spoiler alert! :-)

Comment: whooomp whoomp @Jefromi

Answer (score 2):

> A spoiler!

You can create these with putting ">!" before your text that you want to hide.

```
>! A spoiler!
```

I think a spoiler tag button above the text box for answers is not really necessary here on SA since we don't solve any riddles or reveal spoilers from any novels / video games.